# gcloud ai-platform training: Is it possible to use private repositories as dependencies

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, setuptools, gcp-ai-platform-training

When developing a training package for Google's AI Platform I'd like to use [custom dependencies](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/packaging-trainer) from private github repositories (each having a `setup.py`). What are the options to specify these dependencies with the [`gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ai-platform/jobs/submit/training) command?

The only way I've found in the docs ([adding custom dependencies](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/packaging-trainer)) is to create sdist and/or wheel binary packages (e.g. `dep1.tar.gz` and/or `dep2.whl`) for the dependencies first and then use:

```
gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training $JOB_NAME \
    --staging-bucket $PACKAGE_STAGING_PATH \
    --package-path /Users/mluser/models/faces/trainer \
    --module-name $MAIN_TRAINER_MODULE \
    --packages /gcp-storage/url/or/path/to/dep1.tar.gz, /gcp-storage/url/or/path/to/dep2.whl \
    --region us-central1 \
    -- \
    --user_first_arg=first_arg_value \
    --user_second_arg=second_arg_value
```

As far as I understand, it is only possible to use packages in sdist/wheel format from a local folder or gcp bucket using the [`--packages`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ai-platform/jobs/submit/training#--packages) option.

However, this makes it hard to locally work with these dependencies in editable/development mode because they need to be built (e.g. `python setup.py bdist_wheel`) after each change to get an updated `.whl` file for the next training run.

Is there a way to specify the urls to private git repos directly (including the required credentials for the private repo) or specify a local source directory?

Or is it better to use a [custom container](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/custom-containers-training) or train inside a virtual machine in case I still work in editable/development mode with my dependencies?

Comment: I recommend you the custom container, easier to test locally and  you can use AI-Platform for the training with a custom container.

Comment: Thanks @guillaumeblaquiere, I'll definitely give the custom container a try.